# Wxpython - Sizing related issue with AuiManager

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to create an application with multiple panes using Wxpython - AuiManager. The issue I am having is that if I use centering for Panes, I am unable to do the resizing using the vertical splitter. And if I try to provide bestsize, it doesn't use it. I can see that when I am using bestsize the panels client area is reduced and hence, it doesn't use the full screen area.

A minimal working example is below. Both options can be toggled by changing the truth value of center variable. Can someone help me in getting this to work. I don't want to use SplitterWindows as it needs rework if I decide to increase/decrease the number of panes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui


class Temp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        size = wx.DisplaySize()
        x, y = size
        self.SetSize(size)
        self.SetClientSize(size)
        self.ab = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.mgr = aui.AuiManager(self, aui.AUI_MGR_ALLOW_ACTIVE_PANE)
        self.mgr.AddPane(self.ab, aui.AuiPaneInfo().Top().
                         CaptionVisible(False).Name("ab").Layer(2))
        center = True
        for idx in range(4):
            name = f"Pane {idx+1}"
            if center:
                inf = aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name(name).CaptionVisible(False). \
                    Layer(idx % 2).Center()
            else:
                inf = aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name(name). \
                    CaptionVisible(False).Layer(idx % 2).BestSize(1920, -1)
            pane = wx.Panel(self)
            pane.SetClientSize(size)
            self.mgr.AddPane(pane, inf)
        self.mgr.Update()
        self.SetTitle("Example")
        self.Show()


def main():
    wx.Log.EnableLogging(False)  # Temporary disable to prevent locale error
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    n = Temp(app, None)
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am using KDE - incase this is making a difference